# How to know when user has closed modally presented controller by tapping on title?

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos-2, wkinterfacecontroller

Is there a way to know in code when user has closed a modal by tapping the title? [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/presentControllerWithName:context:) states:

> The title of the modal interface is set to the string Cancel unless the presented interface controller explicitly changes it using the `setTitle:` method. **Tapping the title dismisses the interface automatically.**

As far as I know there is now way to replace that title with a button.

I could fire a notification on `didDeactivate()` or `willDisappear()` but these will also be called when app enters background. So I could do an additional check in *ExtensionDelegate's* `applicationWillResignActive()` to differentiate between user's action in my app or outside my app but this seems very fragile.

Are there any better ways?

Why would one need this?

In my case I have an initial screen where a user makes a choice. After the choice is made I present screens that contain data based on that choice.

I always want to show the data when the choice has been made. So I save the choice and present the modal on app launch when it is present.

But I don't want to show the data if the user has closed the data display. Yet I still want to display the choice made on the first screen. So I can't use the fact that the choice has been made to trigger modal displaying.

Hence I need to know if the modal has dissapeared because of user interaction in app or because the app got switched away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no other way to do so.
But why do you need to add additional checks at `applicationWillResignActive()`? I think there is no need to do so.